# Register google jquery gets overwritten by plugin

Tags: plugins, jquery, wp-register-script

I'm currently using a plugin, which includes jquery version 1.6.4 like this:

```
function thethe_image_slider_head_scripts(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/  jquery.min.js', false, 'latest');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script('slider-ui', THETHE_IMAGE_SLIDER_URL.'style/js/thethe-image-slider.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

The problem is, I'm deregistering jquery in my functions.php file within my theme, to get version 1.7.2. But it still takes the version 1.6.4..

I do like:

```
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script('jquery', (get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"), false, '1.7.2');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Does any know, why it takes the 1.6.4, and not version 1.7.2?

Thanks!

Comment: because the priority of the slider and 1.6.4 means it is executed after the 1.7.2

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: when the function is added, specify a different priority, is your functions.php code inside a hook or is it loose in the global scope? Also can you modify your code to show where `thethe_image_slider_head_scripts` is getting added so that I can see what priority if any it is being given?

Comment: @TomJNowell Please don't post **answers** as **comments**.

Comment: I haven't enough information to fully compose an answer below. When I do I will write up a full answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: **do not de-register core-bundled scripts in order to register some arbitrary version of those scripts**.

WordPress currently (at time of writing) comes bundled with jQuery 1.7.1. When WordPress 3.4 comes out next month, that version will be (IIRC) 1.8.x. Core, Themes, and other Plugins will all rightfully expect the core-bundled version of jQuery to be in use. *Also*, the core-bundled version of jQuery uses **no-conflict mode**, which may not be true when registering an arbitrary version of the script. Thus, you introduce more potential script breakage.

Second: **to override a script de-register/enqueue in a Plugin, you need to *hook into the same action*, and utilize hook *priority*.**

Assuming the Plugin callback `unction thethe_image_slider_head_scripts() {}` is using the default priority, **`10`**, then your own callback needs to use a **lower** priority (i.e. a **higher number**), such as **`11`**, like so:

```
<?php
function wpse48638_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Theme script enqueues go here
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse48638_enqueue_scripts', 11 );
?>
```

Alternatively, you can *remove the Plugin callback from the action*, and then enqueue your own scripts as per normal. Note: the `remove_action()` call *must* use the **same priority** as the Plugin `add_action()` call:

```
<?php
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thethe_image_slider_head_scripts' );
?>
```

(Note that, in both cases, you need to reference the same action that the Plugin is using. It may be `wp_head` or even `init`, instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`.)

#### Edit

Based on this comment:

> Let me see, when I search for the function: thethe_image_slider_head_scripts
>   `add_action('wp_print_scripts', "thethe_image_slider_head_scripts");`

That's exactly what we need!

If you simply want to *remove* the Plugin's script enqueues, just call:

```
<?php
remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'thethe_image_slider_head_scripts' );
?>
```

You have to use the same **priority** as the `add_action()` call, so be sure to leave it as the default (`10`).

#### Edit 2

So, there's one more thing you may need to do, based on this little nugget of wisdom from the Codex:

> It is also worth noting that you may need to prioritise the removal of the action to a hook that occurs after the action is added. You cannot successfully remove the action before it has been added.

**Note: I had to download the Plugin, which required a free "club" membership from the developer, to find this solution. Seeing the *full code* is imperative to answering these sorts of questions.**

The `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'thethe_image_slider_head_scripts' )` function is called from *within another callback*, that itself is hooked into `init`. That's why your `remove_action()` call is failing: because it is firing at an earlier action, when the action you're trying to remove *hasn't yet been added*. So, you need to **wrap your `remove_action()` call inside of a callback *also* hooked into `init`**, like so:

```
<?php
function wpse48638_init_functions() {
    // Remove TheThe Image Slider scripts
    remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'thethe_image_slider_head_scripts' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse48638_init_functions' );
?>
```

Note also that you will probably also need to *re-enqueue* the `'slider-ui'` script that's part of the callback you're removing.

Comment: I know that current version of wordpress gets delivered with 1.7.1, the plugin overwrites the standard jquery. Also from a performance view, loading a jquery internally on the page isn't good, rather using a jquery, from google CDN, because often the jquery is already cached within' the users browser.

Comment: I've tried both the remove_action, and setting the priority higher than the loaded jquery. It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: The Plugin **shouldn't do that**, period. Doing that will cause breakage, whether done in a Plugin or in a Theme. Your question is *prima facie* evidence of such breakage.

Comment: "*I've tried both the remove_action, and setting the priority higher than the loaded jquery. It doesn't work for some reason.*" - For more precise suggestions, we will need to see ALL of the relevant code from both the Plugin and from your Theme, including the full callbacks, and the `add_action()` calls.

Comment: The code I linked in my actual question, is the code, that is there by default.

Comment: The code in your question isn't **full** code. At a minimum, you've omitted the relevant `add_action()` call from the Plugin.

Comment: Chip Bennett, no - because their isn't any add_action() - And I can't find where it's called.. So :) yeah.

Comment: It **must** be there, somewhere. The `wp_enqueue_script()` (etc.) calls are wrapped inside of a *function*, so *something* has to tell that function to *execute*.

Comment: Let me see, when I search for the function: thethe_image_slider_head_scripts

add_action('wp_print_scripts', "thethe_image_slider_head_scripts");

Comment: BINGO! See updated answer.

Comment: So what I should do in my functions.php file is following:

    <?php
    remove_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'thethe_image_slider_head_scripts' );
    ?>

Call the single jquery.cycle.lite kind of script again using
    function someFunction() {
        wp_enqueue_script('slider-ui', THETHE_IMAGE_SLIDER_URL.'style/js/thethe-image-slider.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'someFunction' );

Comment: That should work, yes. Though I would first start with the `remove_action()` call, and verifying that the Plugin's script enqueues are removed from the document head. And *then* enqueue your own scripts, as per normal.

Comment: Now I got to work, to test this. I tried adding the remove_action() - But for some reason, the script is still being loaded :(

Comment: See updated answer. The callback you're trying to remove is wrapped inside a callback that itself is fired at `init`. So, you need to wrap your `remove_action()` call likewise.